# Buttons don't work in android fragments

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, android-inflate

I'm working on an app and I have the following code:

```
package com.S.A.Productions.android.first;

import com.S.A.Productions.android.first.R;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstActivity extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    int counter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lin, container, false);

        TextView temp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        //Set the buttons
        Button button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);


        //+++ BUTTON
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub//Get content of TextView
                TextView temp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                //Convert the string to an integer
                counter = Integer.parseInt(temp.getText().toString());
                counter++;
                temp.setText("" + counter);
                String stringData = temp.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
                editor.putString("sharedString", stringData);
                editor.commit();
            }

        });
        //END OF +++ BUTTON

        return v;
    }


}
```

But when I run the app and I click on that button the app crashes.
I'm using the "v.findViewById"
And at the end I return the v. So I don't know what exactly is wrong.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the trace and your layout lin xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conflict comes because the View **v** inside onclick and inflated view **v**  are different. This code will work:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

int counter;
View v ;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lin, container, false);

    TextView temp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    //Set the buttons
    Button button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);


    //+++ BUTTON
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub//Get content of TextView
            TextView temp = (TextView) this.v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            //Convert the string to an integer
            counter = Integer.parseInt(temp.getText().toString());
            counter++;
            temp.setText("" + counter);
            String stringData = temp.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
            editor.putString("sharedString", stringData);
            editor.commit();
        }

    });
    //END OF +++ BUTTON

    return v;
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand. I just changed the "v" to "myView" now everything works! Thank you so much, I've been trying to get this for many hours now.

Comment: I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: You can "upvote" and "tick" the answers in your questions without reps.

Answer (score 0):

The argument v of the `onClick(View v)` is the element that was clicked, in your case, a `button`.

The error is that You are using argument V (which is a `button`) as a view group by trying to find your text view by Id from the `button` itself. The `textView` will be null. The `setText()` will cause the crash.

You need to use the `findviewbyid()` on any of the containers of the `textView` in the view hierarchy.